# Session superglobal array

Tags: php, superglobals

I just noticed that `session_destroy()` does not seem to be working for me.

Testing PHP code looks like this:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION['session'] = 'session started';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

But the display still shows

```
Array ( [session] => session started)
```

Surely this should throw an error as the SESSION variable now does not exist?

Comment: `session_destroy` destroys the session. That doesn't mean you can't then re-create it.

Comment: Try adding `unset($_SESSION);` that won't show the array anymore; if that's what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_destroy` destroys the saved session data - in most cases, that's the session file.

However, it doesn't affect the session variable itself.

Therefore, so long as you are in the same request, you can continue to use the `$_SESSION` superglobal with all its previous values. To completely destroy that, you should use:

```
foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $k) unset($_SESSION[$k]);
```

Or code to similar effect.

That said, it doesn't matter much - the session will be destroyed, and usually you only do this on logout pages that will only be displayed briefly before sending the user back to the homepage.

Comment: Thanks so much for that - new information to me but very useful. Issue resolved